# Dynamic checkboxes inside of a table being built by foreach knockout.js - Set dependencies as enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, foreach

I've got a markup with a table, which has three columns ( 1st: Checkbox , 2nd: Product description - being retrieved through restful & webservices, 3rd: Quantity input), as you can see in the code below.

```
<thead>
     <tr>
          <th> Select </th>
          <th><center>Product Description</center></th>
          <th style="width: 150px; text-align: center">Quantity</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody data-bind="foreach: productsList">
     <tr> 
        <td>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkproduct" 
                 data-bind="checked: $parent.myproduct" 
                 style="padding-top:80px;width: 30px;height:20px" id="checkproduct">
            </fieldset>
        </td>

        <td>
            <p data-bind="text:productTextDescription"></p> 
        </td>

        <td>
           <input type="number" name="quantity" step="10.0" data-clear-btn="true"
            class="quantity" id="inputquantity" style="height: 55px"/>
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I was wondering how a subscription can be linked to each of those dynamic checkboxex in order to set as enabled its linked quantity-input. Essentially, each row inside the table represents a "whole package" (meaning that if a product is selected its quantity cannot be empty) of client-side data which is meant to be sent through code, restful and web services for doing some stuff afterwards.

I've been able to set a subscription with $parent.myproduct but it doesn't work as expected. Any time I check any of them, all of them get checked. Any guesses on what can possibly be wrong?

My subscription goes as follows:

```
myViewModel.myproduct.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if(newValue){
      console.log(newValue);
    }
 });
```

I've made a bit of research, but seemingly these are the ones which seem more likely to be helpful:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Jm2Mh/

[Knockout checkbox enable dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335762/knockout-checkbox-enable-dependencies) (Jsfiddle isn't working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
   <td>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkproduct" 
             data-bind="checked: $data.isChecked" 
            style="padding-top:80px;width: 30px;height:20px" />
        </fieldset>
    </td>

    <td>
        <p data-bind="text: $data.productTextDescription"></p> 
    </td>

    <td>
       <input type="number" name="quantity" step="10.0" data-clear-btn="true"
        data-bind="enable: $data.isChecked, value: $data.quantity"
        class="quantity" style="height: 55px"/>
    </td>


var product = function(desc, isChecked, quantity) {
    this.isChecked = ko.observable(isChecked);
    this.quantity = ko.observable(quantity);
    this.productTextDescription = ko.observable(desc);
}

var viewmodel = function () {
    this.productsList = ko.observableArray();   
    this.productsList.push(new product("first product"));
    this.productsList.push(new product("second product"));
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W86XS/)